# Comparing values in two lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

In Python 2.7, I have two lists of integers:

```
x = [1, 3, 2, 0, 2]
y = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

I want to create a third list which indicates whether each element in `x` and `y` is identical, to yield:

```
z = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

How can I do this using list comprehension?

My attempt is:

```
z = [i == j for i,j in ...]
```

But I don't know how to complete it.

Comment: I think you'll get a list of booleans. If you like it to be 0,1, you'll probably need to do some casting

Comment: @SomethingSomething Yes. you need to cast to an `int`. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32996311/4099593) :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
z = [i == j for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

But you better add [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) call to get your desired output

```
>>> z = [int(i == j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
>>> z
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

else you'll get a list like `[True, False, True, False, False]`

---

As [ajcr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923281/ajcr) mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996293/comparing-values-in-two-lists/32996311?noredirect=1#comment53817743_32996311), it is better to use   itertools.izip instead of zip if the lists are very long. This is because it returns an iterator instead of a list. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

> Like zip() except *that it returns an iterator* instead of a list.

demo

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> z = [int(i == j) for i,j in izip(x,y)]
>>> z
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: A small footnote: if the lists are very long, it might be worth using `itertools.izip` instead of `zip` to avoid the construction of a long list of tuples. Python 3 does not have this issue, of course.

Comment: @ajcr Perfect. I always forget that (Py3 problems). I will add a small note there. Thanks.

Comment: So without using `itertools.izip` (or Python 3), it would run `zip(x,y)` for every element in `x` and `y`?

Comment: @Karnivaurus In python3 `zip` returns an iterator by itself. You can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: Just to also point out, the cast to int is not really necessary as python will treat `True` and `False` as `1` and `0` respectively if you try to do any math on them.

Answer (score 3):

You can change it a little bit and do:

```
[x[i] == y[i] for i in xrange(len(x))]
```

If you use Python3 - change `xrange` to `range`

Comment: This is valid, but the more pythonic solution is to use `zip`.

Comment: The advantage of zip is that it handles lists of different length.

Answer (score 1):

While a list comprehension was specified in the question and the answers above are probably better, I thought I'd chime in with a recursive solution:

```
def compare_lists(a, b, res=[]):
    if len(a) == len(b):
        if a == []:
            return res
        else:
            if a[0] == b[0]:
                res.append(1)
            else:
                res.append(0)
            return compare_lists(a[1:], b[1:])
    else:
        return "Lists are of different length."
```