# Comparing two lists and making new list

Tags: python, list, compare

So lets say I have two lists `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `b=[2,34,5,67,5,6]` I want to create a third list which will have `1` where elements are different in `a` and `b` and `0` when they are same, so above would be like `c=[1,1,1,1,0,0]`

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
This is a trivial iteration and comparison -- you should be able to produce useful code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can zip the lists and compare them in a list comprehension. This takes advantage of the fact that booleans are equivalent to 1 and 0 in python:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
b=[2,34,5,67,5,6] 

[int(m!=n) for m, n, in zip(a, b)]
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Hopefully, the world has moved on from python 2.7 by now, but note that this will clobber a and b afterwards due to the odd way list comprehensions have different scopes between python 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks @RichL that was a little sloppy (even without considering 2.7) -- I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a list comprehension over elements of each pair of items in the list with `zip`:

```py
[ 0 if i == j else 1 for i,j in zip(a,b) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating with a for loop is an option, though list comprehension may be more efficient.

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
b=[2,34,5,67,5,6]
c=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == b[i]:
        c.append(0)
    else:
        c.append(1)
print(c)
```

prints

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will have multiple vector operations and they should be fast. Checkout `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
b=[2,34,5,67,5,6]
a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = (a != b).astype(int)
# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

idk if this is exactly what youre loocking for but this should work:

edidt: just found out that Joe Thor commented almost the exact same a few minutes earlier than me lmao

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [2, 34, 5, 67, 5, 6]
results = []

for f in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[f] == b[f]:
        results.append(0)
    else:
        results.append(1)

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly simply using a for loop. It does assume that both lists, a and b, are the same length. An example code would like something like this:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [2,34,5,67,5,6]
c = []
if len(a) == len(b):
   for i in range(0,len(a)):
       if(a[i] != b[i]):
         c.append(1)
       else:
         c.append(0)
```

This can also be done using list comprehension:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [2,34,5,67,5,6]
c = []
if len(a) == len(b):
    c = [int(i != j) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

The list comprehension code is from this thread: [Comparing values in two lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996293/comparing-values-in-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [2, 34, 5, 67, 5,6]
c = []

index = 0
x = 1
y = 0
for i in range(len(a)):    # iterating loop from index 0 till the last 
    if a[index]!= b[index]:    # comapring each index 
            c.append(x)         # if not equal append c with '1'
            index += 1           # increment index to move to next index in both lists
    else:
            c.append(y)
            index += 1

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for two lists of any type.

```
tstlist = ["w","s","u"]
lstseasons = ["s","u","a","w"]

lstbool_Seasons = [1 if ele in tstlist else 0 for ele in lstseasons]
```

Output: lstbool_Seasons = [1,1,0,1]

This is the first time I have posted anything, still figuring out how things work here, so please forgive faux pas...